# ionic: multible buttons in header not displaying correct

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a Header with one button on the left side, a title also on the left and 6 buttons on the right side. However only the last button is displayed on the right the rest on the left. When wrapping all the buttons in a div all of them are on the left side([output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnmG5.png)). and using ionics button-bar class for the div displayes them over the full width.

html:

```
<ion-header-bar style=" background-color:#3A5B89">
      <button menu-toggle="left" > menu</button>
    <h1 class="title" style=" text-align:left; color:white;">Medexter Demo KIS</h1>
      <div class="BTNright">
      <button class="button button-clear button-light BTNright" >Print</button>
      <button class="button button-clear button-light BTNright">Back</button>
      <button class="button button-clear button-light BTNright">Redo</button>
      <button class="button button-clear button-light BTNright">Search</button>
      <button class="button button-clear button-light BTNright">Help</button>
      <button class="button button-clear button-light BTNright">Log Out</button>
      </div>
  </ion-header-bar>
```

style for BTNright:

```
.BTNright{
float:right ;
font-size: 80%;
```

}

Edit: 
[How it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnmG5.png)

Comment: can you send me the demo output how your UI should be look like so that it will be easy to understand

Comment: I added the current state. however I can only add one image so I can't show you what it's supposed to look like. I hope this still helps

Comment: K have you tried **Grid** in your header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified HTML

```
<ion-header-bar style=" background-color:#3A5B89">
      <button menu-toggle="left" > menu</button>
    <h1 class="title" style=" text-align:left; color:white;">Medexter Demo KIS</h1>
      <div class="BTNright">
      <button class="button button-clear button-light  " >Print</button>
      <button class="button button-clear button-light  ">Back</button>
      <button class="button button-clear button-light  ">Redo</button>
      <button class="button button-clear button-light  ">Search</button>
      <button class="button button-clear button-light  ">Help</button>
      <button class="button button-clear button-light  ">Log Out</button>
      </div>
  </ion-header-bar>
```

CSS

```
.BTNright{
position:absolute ;
right:0px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I clicked it but for some reason it won't show. maybe I can't upvoat jet.

Comment: Actually that's what <ion-nav-bar> and <ion-nav-buttons side="secondary"> are for: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavButtons/

There is no need to do this on your own by CSS.